# C++ bad memory alloc exception

Tags: c++, sql, multithreading, performance, exception

Here is a gist of what I am trying to do. I store files in SQL table. The table is large with 400 records but each record stores the file archive and their size is approximately 100MB each. Recently, we had to change our encryption key.So I am writing a threaded ( 5 threads ) code to decrypt using the legacy key and then encrypt using the new key.This is what each thread does

```
struct DataToReencrypt
{
     int id;
     string data;
}
vector<DataToReencrypt> results;

// database open
SELECT ID,FileData From Files WHERE ID BETWEEN 1 AND 80 // 81-160 and so on.
// database connection close

// database connection open
for(int i=0;i<results.size();i++ )  // results contain the result of the above query.
{
    string decrypted = LegacyDecryption(results[i].FileData);
    string encrypted = NewEncryption(decrypted);

    UPDATE Files SET FileData = encrypted WHERE ID = results[i].ID;
}
// database connection close
```

The problem is when I am trying to do this,I get this C++ bad_memory alloc exception and also SQL Memory alloc exception. While I was reading through the bad_memory alloc exception I read C++ throws it when the compiler cannot allocate new memory. Just in case if this helps, I am running this on a system with 6GB RAM ( I have to make this work in 6GB RAM as it is the minimum our product supports) and while this process runs the sqlserver.exe process takes almost close 4GB of RAM space. Please help with any problem with this approach or anyways that it could be improved.

Comment: I'm not sure there's much to go on here, you're running out of memory. Generally the solution is to use less memory.

Comment: Just to be clear - each record is 100MB and you are reading 80 of them into memory? That isn't going to fit in 6GB

Comment: @TheDark You are right. The maximum file size is 100MB. At least half of the files are less. But I don't want to bank on assumption for future proofing. Also, this runs correctly once in 2 or 3 times. So I assume it is memory issue. Anyway to improve the process here?

Comment: I would say it would be best to just have each thread read one item at a time and process that. That way each thread would use a max of 200MB of memory (approximately). So just put the select statement inside the loop and only select 1 item at a time. You can still use an outer select to get the IDs if they aren't always contiguous.

Comment: @TheDark Thanks for your suggestion. The problem with this approach is the ID field should be contiguous. In general, how can we modify if the ID is not contiguous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@TheDark gave a good suggestion in his last comment. If it were me and i knew the count in the table or i could retrieve the data count, then i would do something similar to the following:

```
// database connection open
for(int i=0;i<80;i++ )  // ...160...240...etc for each thread
{
    string data;

    SELECT ID,FileData From Files WHERE ID = i // 81-160 and so on.

    // data = FileData from query

    string decrypted = LegacyDecryption(data);
    string encrypted = NewEncryption(decrypted);

    UPDATE Files SET FileData = encrypted WHERE ID = i;
}
// database connection close
```

This would reduce the amount of memory used by far and rid yourself of the struct. Granted this would mean that your id's are contiguous, but i'm figuring they are since you are using a table for this specific type of data.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. How will this change if the ID is not contiguous?

Comment: @Crusher: If the id's are not contiguous then i assume you are querying with a different WHERE condition. I would outside the loop do a "SELECT ID WHERE X = Y" and store the data into a vector<ints> ids without the FILEDATA (this should be within your required memory size as this will only be a vector of ints). Then use the vector.size() to adjust the for loops and and the data within the vector to query the table WHERE ID = Vector.at(i). Hope that makes sense...